# jquery bind and unbind without function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Objective**

- A division is clicked.
- The contents of that division changes to a form field to update it.
- The "click" event is removed so form field and button can be clicked
- The form is generated with default value etc from database using `$("#x").load`
- The data is saved via `$.post` and form is removed and replace by the new value.
- The division should now become clickable again **< PROBLEM**

What I've tried so far...

I have lots of divisions with multiple "data-?" attributes for different uses. I'll keep my examples simple

```
<div class="profile_value" id="div1" data-id="1" data-name="john">
    <span id="field1">John</span>
</div>
<div class="profile_value" id="div2" data-id="2" data-name="alan">
    <span id="field2">Alan</span>
</div>
```

**USING .ON();** - problem is unbinding

```
$("body").on("click", ".profile_value", function(){
    var pid = $(this).data("id");
    var name = $(this).data("name");
    $("#field"+pid).load("ajax/form/etc.etc.php");
    //now i can't seem to unbind the click with this method
    //i've tried $(this).off("click");
}
```

So even when the form field that's loaded via ajax with data from database is clicked, it just reloads the form again as another "click" is triggered.

**USING .CLICK();** - problem is re-binding

With this, part 1 works perfectly...

```
$(".profile_value").click(function(){
    var pid = $(this).data("id");
    var name = $(this).data("name");
    $("#field"+pid).load("ajax/form/etc.etc.php");
    $(this).off("click"); //this works
});
```

And then when form is submitted (via ajax), on success it removes the form successfully and displays new data. However, this time I can't re-bind the click.

I've tried `.bind("click")` pointing to it's specific #ID and `.on("click");` in various ways. No luck!

**Note:** Docs shows examples but all with external functions. I am using this on many divisions so a function doesn't seem suitable (I could be wrong)

**Note 2:** Other answers on SO also show many examples but all with functions and only one single clickable button or div.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but this makes no sense? What exactly are you asking, and how would you bind an event handler without a function, what's it supposed to do ?

Comment: @adeneo Sorry I think I typed too much as I've over done the trials and errors. Let me edit and summarise objective first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your event handler is triggered via delegation - the event propagates up the DOM until it hits the the `body`, and then triggers. `.profile_value` elements don't actually have the event directly bound to them, so using `.off('click')` on the individual elements won't work.

Using `$('body').off('click', '.ele')` would remove the handler from all elements, but this is not ideal.

An easy solution is to attach a new handler that stops the propagation of the click event. You can even use it to let the user know that the element has already been clicked.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/rudaze/1/edit?js,console,output)</kbd>

```js
$('body').on('click', '.ele', function (e) {
  console.log('Clicked!');
  $(this).on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('New click handler, that stops propagation to the old handler.');
  });
});

$('.rebind').on('click', function () {
  $('.ele').off('click');
  console.log('A general rebind.');
});
```

```css
.ele {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background-color: pink;
}

.rebind {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="ele"></div>
<div class="ele"></div>
<div class="ele"></div>
<div class="ele"></div>
<div class="ele"></div>

<button class="rebind">Rebind them all</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To 'rebind' the delegated handler use `.off('click')` on the individual elements.

Reading material:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)
- [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Thanks for understanding the issue and answering so clearly. Good job. This will do just fine

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you are trying to do, but to unbind a handler from delegate listener, you can use this..

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/xot6qocd/2/)

```
<div class="profile_value" id="div1" data-id="1" data-name="john">
    <span id="field1">John</span>
</div>
<div class="profile_value" id="div2" data-id="2" data-name="alan">
    <span id="field2">Alan</span>
</div>
```

```
var profile_click_handler = function() {
    var target = $(event.currentTarget);
    alert("clicked");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("body").off("click", ".profile_value", profile_click_handler);
        console.log("clicked off", target );
        alert("click unbound");
    }, 2000);
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".profile_value", profile_click_handler);
});
window.rebind = function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".profile_value", profile_click_handler);
}
```

Comment: Please see updated question. What part is not clear about what I'm trying to do? Thanks

Comment: The timer is what put my off from using this. There's no need for it plus I didn't want to use function remember? :) Thanks anyway, I've gone another route, answered own Q

Comment: The timer is not required for it to work :) it was just a way to simulate ajax load/async function. You would have your ajax function instead of the timer

Answer (score 0):

Add another parameter to your divisions:

```
<div class="profile_value" id="div1" data-id="1" data-click="0" data-name="john">
    <span id="field1">John</span>
</div>
```

Everytime new divisions are created they will have `data-click="0"` but when clicked that should change to `data-click="1"`. That way you can check if the division has been clicked or not. Does that make sense or I completely missunderstoo your question?

Comment: No that's too much going on for a rather simple thing :) thanks for suggestion. I've gone another way - answered own question

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems either I can't describe my problem clearly or everyone is simply rushing or tired :)

I have solved it by making the form appear in another division immediately after the `.profile_values` div so no more need to bind unbind. I just `hide()` the clicked `div` and show it again once form is submitted.

That was my solution to this annoying bind-unbind-rebind-on-off-live

Comment: I'm gonna stick with number 1: you just can't describe your problem. Your answer is more convoluted than your question, if possible.

Comment: @DaseinA I guess the accepted answer suggests otherwise. It's most definitely number 2